# Naïve question about manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

On [this youtube video by XylyXylyX](https://youtu.be/SqB23B8ZBIc?t=4m158s)
 explaining curves on differentiable manifolds the following drawing is presented:

[image]

with $(X,\mathcal T_X,\mathcal A)$ denoting a topological space, i.e. $(X,\mathcal T_X),$ with Housdorff, second countability and paracompactness, and an atlas, $\mathcal A;$ $f(\lambda)$ plotting the real line to the manifold: $\mathbb R \to X$, so as to parametrize the line in black on the manifold; and $\gamma$ and $\phi$ representing charts $X\to \mathbb R^2$ (or $\mathbb R^d)$ for different chart regions $U$ and $V.$

It is clear how after we land safely in Euclidean space through $\gamma$ and $\phi$ we can apply calculus; however, and before we get there (or to change coordinates) we have to go through $X$. And if $X$ is not in Euclidean space,

> What mathematical form does $f$ assume? It can't be $y = f(\lambda),$ which would imply coordinates.

Can I have an example (other than the sterographic world map)?

Comment: Would [math.se] be  a better home for this question?

Comment: I removed the Gen. Relativity tag

Comment: @magma Thank you. It made some sense in the Physics forum, since the lectures linked are focused on the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We define differentiability of maps between manifolds (and many other things) in coordinate representations because that is precisely the only way we can "concretely" deal with them.

If you want to explicitly give a curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ you will always give $(\varphi\circ\gamma)(t)=(x^1(t),...,x^n(t))$. If you want to explicitly give a function $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, you will always give $(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(x^1,...,x^n)$.

The construction holds because differentiability (and other properties) do not depend on the coordinates. You see, if we only allow $C^{\infty}$ coordinate transformations, then if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are both chart functions, then if, say, $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^k$ function, because $f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is $C^k$, then $f\circ\psi^{-1}=f\circ\varphi^{-1}\circ\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}=(f\circ\varphi^{-1})\circ(\varphi\circ\psi^{-1})$, where the expression in the first parentheses is $C^k$ by our postulate (but it can be explicitly checked, as this is just an $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function), and the expression in the second parentheses is a change-of-coordinates function, which is $C^{\infty}$ because both charts are part of the manifold's maximal smooth atlas.

Now, the composition of a $C^k$ function with a $C^{\infty}$ function is $C^{k}$, so if the coordinate representation $f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is $C^{k}$ for any one chart, then the coordinate representation $f\circ\psi^{-1}$ will also be $C^{k}$ *automatically*.

The coordinate-free forms are there only to make 'theoretical' or 'abstract' statements. When you want to calculate things explicitly, the only way to do it is by working directly with the representations $f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ and the likes.

Comment: I'm teaching myself these concepts, and I'm getting stuck on the Greek notation. For instance, when you say that the curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ is $(\varphi\circ\gamma)(t)=(x^1(t),...,x^n(t)),$ is this composition of functions the equivalent of "eating" a $t\in \mathbb R$, "mapping" it to the manifold, but not really, because in the manifold there is no coordinate system, and hence, we immediately need to send it to Euclidean coordinates via an implicit function $\varphi$ that would go from the "idea" in the manifold to something workable in $\mathbb R^d?$

Comment: @AntoniParellada Yes, that's about it. $\gamma$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to the manifold $M$, $\gamma(t)$ is a point of $M$. But we cannot give such an object explicitly. The map $\varphi$ is a chart map. It is a *local* function from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $p\in M$ is a point of $M$, then $\varphi(p)=(x^1(p),...,x^n(p))$ gives the coordinates of $p$ (in this chart). We can then compose the two: The map $\varphi\circ\gamma$ is a map that sends a number to a point of $M$, then maps that abstract points into its coordinates.

Comment: +1 (same for Javier's answer)... So the case of the [stereographic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) of the World where the globe is a 2-sphere in $\mathbb R^3$, and the maps leaving one single point out either in the North or South Poles, are from this manifold set to $2D$ following trigonometric functions is more the exception than the rule?

Comment: @AntoniParellada More exception than the rule? Well, it depends. Theoretically speaking? Definitely. Practically speaking? In practice, when you work on any 'concrete' manifold, you need to actually specify that manifold. This specification may differ case-by-case, but will often give you some preferred coordinates. Common cases include:

* Manifold is embedded in euclidean space. Your sphere is an example of this.
* Manifold is a connected component of a Lie group, the one which contains the identity. In this case, you can use the exponential map to give a chart directly...

Comment: @AntoniParellada What else,

* Manifold is given as an *open* subset of euclidean space. This might sound odd but this is how spacetimes are given in GR. You usually assume some coordinate system (eg. an open subset of euclidean space) and you solve for the metric components. You will get an open subset of euclidean space with a usually non-euclidean metric. This is not the entire manifold of course, but usually it is enough to work locally.

* You can actually give a manifold exactly by giving multiple open sets of euclidean space with some system of transition functions. This is rare tho

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is a function that takes a real number and returns a point in $X$. If you don't have a concrete definition of $X$ (perhaps as a subset of $R^n$) and you don't use coordinates, then you can't write a formula for $f$, because the elements of $X$ are just abstract points.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking, but then the question is, how can that construct hold?

Comment: @AntoniParellada You don't need a formula to define a function. Or maybe I should say, you don't need a formula for a function to exist. The function itself exists in a sort of abstract way; you need an explicit formula if you want to actually work with it.

Comment: Thank you, Javier! So what I gather is that in the OP, as well as in the edit I just posted, the functions on manifold are never explicitly or implicitly formulated, and that the curves drawn on the manifold are just conceptual ideas. Then, how is it possible to find the formulas describing mappings on the Euclidean coordinate systems?

Comment: @AntoniParellada even in the real numbers, a function can exist without having an explicit formula. A function is after all a correspondence between two sets; this correspondence can exist even if there is no way to define it concretely. The same happens here: if you ever have to work with a concrete function, you need a coordinate system to define it. But the curves drawn are more than conceptual ideas: the functions actually do exist, even if you have no way to write an expression for them.

Answer (score 0):

However, sometimes there actually is an explicit function f. Consider a set of, say, for ordered numbers (x,y,z,w) such that the sum of their squares equals the constant A. That set is “M” in the diagram above. You can easily construct a function from [0,1] into that set of order quadruples. M, it turns out, is a manifold, and can be given coordinates (in an almost obvious way) and an atlas. “F” can be explicitly constructed and so can the chart mappings.

You forbade the stereographic projection as an example, that would be one way of constructing charts in this case. There are others however. Lot’s of others.

Regarding spacetime, we are dealing with the abstract idea of spacetime as the set M. That is why it is an **axiom** of GR that spacetime is a 4-D manifold. This assumption guarantees that we can do everything in terms of some set of coordinates. The next assumption is that the laws of nature do not depend on the choice of coordinates and that leads to all laws being in tensorial form. So the “actual set M of spacetime” is there to help us understand that we are modeling spacetime via the mathematics of a manifold.